# User not being saved, SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-edittext

Hi i have a inlogscreen (inlogdialog.xml), which includes 2 EditText (username, passwd) and i have a CheckBox (saveuser) with which the user can decide weather to save the username or not.

On the mainform (main.xml) i have a listner for these 3 values:

```
private class OnReadyListener implements MyCustomForm.ReadyListener {

    public void ready(String user, String pass, boolean save) {
        username = user;
        password = pass;
    }

}
```

Now i first want to save the username through SharedPreferences but it doesn`t get saved, can someone help me please?

If i check with system.out.println, the username is present in String username.

SharedPreferenes code in main.xml:

```
public static final String USERNM = ""; 
private SharedPreferences mPrefs; 
.......

@Override     
protected void onPause() {  
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();   
    e.putString(USERNM, username); <----
    e.commit();     
    Toast.makeText(this, "Items saved.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
    super.onPause();    
}
```

Edit:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "SharedPrefsDemoPreferences";  
public static final String PREF_BOOL = "Bool"; 
public static final String USERNM = "User"; 

private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
....
@Override 
protected void onResume() { 
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0); 
    if(mPrefs!=null) 
        myBoxState=mPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_BOOL, false); 
    super.onResume(); 
}
```

Edit 2:

```
@Override     
protected void onPause() { 
    System.out.println("user: " + username); <---- value username is there
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();   
    //e.putBoolean(PREF_BOOL, nieuwbel.isChecked()); 
    e.putString(USERNM, username);
    e.commit(); 
    Toast.makeText(this, "Instelling beltegoed opgeslagen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
    super.onPause();    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better not use **empty key** for the username. Saving data in SharedPreferences is based on saving a key-value pair. You retrieve the value by providing the key. Currently the key for your username is empty string.

Try something like:

```
    //initialize some default values and keys for the SharedPreferences
private static final String DEF_USERNAME_KEY = "prefsUsername";
private static final String DEF_USERNAME_VALUE = "def_username_value";

private static final String DEF_PASSWORD_KEY = "prefsPassword";
private static final String DEF_PASSWORD_VALUE = "def_pass_value";

private void saveUserData(String username, String password) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor userPrefsEditor = userPrefs.edit();

    userPrefsEditor.putString(DEF_USERNAME_KEY, username); 
    userPrefsEditor.putString(DEF_PASSWORD_KEY, password);

    userPrefsEditor.commit();

            //check if data is saved
    Log.d(TAG, "Getting from SharedPreferences " + DEF_USERNAME_KEY + " " + 
            userPrefs.getString(DEF_USERNAME_KEY, DEF_USERNAME_VALUE)); 
    Log.d(TAG, "Getting from SharedPreferences " + DEF_PASSWORD_KEY + " " + 
            userPrefs.getString(DEF_PASSWORD_KEY, DEF_PASSWORD_VALUE)); 
}
```

Edit: This is how you retrieve from SharedPreferences:

```
userPrefs.getString(DEF_USERNAME_KEY, DEF_USERNAME_VALUE)
```

IN your case this will look like:

```
String returnedUsername = e.getString(USERNM, "");
```

than `returnedUsername` holds the value you stored in SharedPrefs.

Comment: Hi hovanessyan,
First thx for answering, i now gave USERNM a value: public static final String USERNM = "User" as you suggested but it still does not get saved.
FYI the username is being passed from another form inlogdialog.xml to the OnReadyListener in the main form main.xml.
If i check the username it is there but when i commit i get the value User?

Comment: How do you mean?
This is what i have for now for testing purposes.

Comment: Ok edited the code with my getsharedpreferences, i am also working on saving the state of some checkboxes, that`s the myBoxState.
I did not put a code in there for the username, as i first want to save it and then retrieve it.
How should it then look like?

Comment: things look OK in your code. Probably they got messed up somewhere else. Try to log the value of your username variable and see if it's there, just before you save it in SharedPrefs. Apart from that, the way you work with SharedPrefs is OK.

Comment: Ok, thx for confirming but it`s weird.
I check the value as you suggested, see Edit 2 in my code.
Hmmm

Comment: ok - so it gets saved... Maybe you post how you retrieve it then?

Comment: That`s the point it doesn`t get saved.
If i do:
e.putString(USERNM, username);
System.out.println("user: " + USERNM); << returns the value User, which i declared USERNM with and not the actuel username.
Or do i see things wrongly?
I am quit new to sharedpreferences.

Comment: see the Edit. You should read the documentation of SharedPreferences again.

Comment: Worked! So it does get saved.
I will follow youre advise, thx for the efforts hovanessyan.

Answer (score 2):

Your key for the `username` is empty (see: `public static final String USERNM = "";`), that's too bad. You need a key for every value.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)